# DataFrame, adding value from DF1 in specific row in DF2 if specific columns value is in DF1

Tags: python, pandas

I have been searching a lot on SO and in pandas's help but couldn't find what I am looking for.

I have 2 dataframes with those columns :

```
Index([u'id', u'date', u'heure', u'titre'], dtype='object')

Index([u'article', u'id', u'type', u'rubrique', u'source', u'rebond_global',
   u'chargement_global', u'visites_global'],
  dtype='object')
```

What I'd love to be able to do is to keep the second one and to add data contained in the first dataframe using the 'id' as a key.

My final DataFrame always feels like I have made an append and added the new columns.

This is, amongst others, what I have tried :

Join method :

```
df1.set_index('id').join(df2.set_index('id'))
```

Merge method :

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='id')
```

In a way, what i'm trying to do is something similar to "if id from Dataframe 1 is in DataFrame 2 then create columns 'date', 'heure' and 'titre' in DataFrame 2 and fill with value from Dataframe 1"

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use df2 as a basis, then join df1 using column 'id':

```
df2.join(df1.set_index('id'), 'id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
merged = pd.merge(left=df1[["id", "date", "heure", "titre"]], right=df2, on="id", how="inner")
```

**Edit:** Full example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "date": [10, 20, 30, 40],
    "heure": ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"],
    "titre": ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"]
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 2, 3, 5],
    "article": ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a5"]
    })

merged = pd.merge(left=df1[["id", "date", "heure", "titre"]], right=df2, on="id", how="inner")

print "DF1:\n", df1
print "DF2:\n", df2
print "Merged:\n", merged
```

Prints:

```
DF1:
   date heure  id titre
0    10    h1   1    t1
1    20    h2   2    t2
2    30    h3   3    t3
3    40    h4   4    t4
DF2:
  article  id
0      a1   1
1      a2   2
2      a3   3
3      a5   5
Merged:
   id  date heure titre article
0   1    10    h1    t1      a1
1   2    20    h2    t2      a2
2   3    30    h3    t3      a3
```

Comment: Thanks Plasma, it wasn't working at first and just throw me an empty DataFrame. Your comment made me believe that something wrong was occuring in some other places. Turns out that df1.id was unicode while df2.id was numpy.int64.

I had to use the following code : df1["id"] = pd.to_numeric(df1.id, errors='coerce')